# Hop blend for NEIPA

Tags: hops

Will try brewing NEIPA for the first time. The the grain bill is very simple.

- Volume 5.5 gallons.
- 6 kg. Maris Otter
- 1 kg. Rolled oats
- 2 packs of Safale S-04

Hops available:

- 60 g. Cascade
- 60 g. Mosaic
- 50 g. Ahtanum
- 50 g. Simcoe
- 150 g. Citra

Looking for fresh citrusy profile.

Hop schedule:

- First wort : 20 g Cascade/
- Whirlpool Stepping under 80 c for 20 min.:

  - 25 g. Ahtanum
  - 25 g. Citra
  - 25 g. Mosaic
- High Krausen:

  - 25 g. Ahtanum
  - 25 g. Mosaic
  - 35 g. Citra
- Dry hop for 7 days:

  - 35 g. Cascade
  - 20 g. Simcoe
  - 40 g. Citra.

Does this hop combination look good or would you change something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a nice recipe for a  "Juicy" IPA.  Hops sound delicious. The oats and MO will make it like opaque blood orange juice when done right. (ruby orange).